# Change HTML characters in URL in xcode

Tags: iphone, url, ios4, character

given a URL like this:

http%3A%2F%2Fwww.environmental-expert.com%2FresultEachPressRelease.aspx%3Fcid%3D23745%26codi%3D234441%26lr%3D1

How can i replace the characters (like %3D and so on) to get a normal url using the iphone sdk?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
NSString *myEscapedUrl = @"http%3A%2F%2Fwww.environmental-expert.com%2FresultEachPressRelease.aspx%3Fcid%3D23745%26codi%3D234441%26lr%3D1";

NSLog(@"my unescaped url: %@", [myEscapedUrl stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
```